# How to check all geotargeting options in DV360?

Tags: google-ads-api, dv360

Google Ads API provides a [list of all geo locations](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/data/geotargets) in its documentation.

Does this list also apply to DV360? I could not find an equivalent but I assume they are at least similar.